# Python Tkinter Treeview Filters

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to filter the columns in the treeview widget like excel.  I found this code on stack overflow (by oskros) and it accomplishes this task, but what if I want to filter a single column by more than one value.  This code only allows one value to filter on.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

inp = [{'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'DK'},
       ]


class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Volume")

        combofr = Frame(self)
        combofr.pack(expand=True, fill=X)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='headings')
        columns = list(inp[0].keys())

        self.filters = []

        for col in columns:
            name = 'combo_' + col
            self.filters.append(name)
            setattr(self, name, ttk.Combobox(combofr, values=[
                    ''] + sorted(set(x[col] for x in inp)), state="readonly"))
            getattr(self, name).pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=X)
            getattr(self, name).bind(
                '<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.select_from_filters)

        self.tree["columns"] = columns
        self.tree.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

        for i in columns:
            self.tree.column(i, anchor="w")
            self.tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor="w")

        for i, row in enumerate(inp):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=i, values=list(row.values()))

    def select_from_filters(self, event=None):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        def all_filter(x): return all(x[f.split('_')[-1]] == getattr(
            self, f).get() or getattr(self, f).get() == '' for f in self.filters)
        for row in inp:
            if all_filter(row):
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=list(row.values()))


root = Application()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this version, but you have to type the values in and if there are allot of records you would need to scroll down to find all the ones you need to filter on.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

inp = [{'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'DK'},
       ]


def trim(list):
    return list.replace(" ", "")


class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Volume")

        combofr = Frame(self)
        combofr.pack(expand=True, fill=X)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='headings')
        columns = list(inp[0].keys())

        self.filters = []

        for col in columns:
            name = 'combo_' + col
            self.filters.append(name)
            setattr(self, name, ttk.Entry(combofr))
            getattr(self, name).pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=X)
            getattr(self, name).bind(
                '<Return>', self.select_from_filters)

        self.tree["columns"] = columns
        self.tree.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

        for i in columns:
            self.tree.column(i, anchor="w")
            self.tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor="w")

        for i, row in enumerate(inp):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=i, values=list(row.values()))

    def select_from_filters(self, event=None):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        filters = [list(map(trim, getattr(self, f).get().split(",")))
                   for f in self.filters]

        print(filters)

        def all_filter(x): return all(x[f.split('_')[-1]] in filters[i] or getattr(
            self, f).get() == '' for i, f in enumerate(self.filters))
        for row in inp:
            if all_filter(row):
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=list(row.values()))


root = Application()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).